# How to prevent a cloth from entering another mesh?

Tags: modifiers, objects, physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to create a cloth simulation on a human body. I created a shirt and I am trying to see the pattern of folds and how it drapes on a human. I applied cloth modifier to the shirt and collision modifier to the human. The simulation seems just fine, but here is the problem. The shirt starts entering into the human body and develops some weird folds and sharp features. How can I avoid such intersection of cloth and the body? I don't want to do a shrink wrap - I want to simulate a realistic shirt on a human.

Answer (score 4):

Blender cloth sim are perfect for dropping tablecloths onto tables, they rarely work well for shirts (although they will work for skirts).

That said, if you have it working, more or less, here are some tips for better shirt sims:

1. Under collision, enable `Self Collision`, this will try and help with the cloth hitting itself.
2. Lower all the distance settings way down, including collision.
3. Your shirt mesh density and topology will have a huge impact. In general, an all quad mesh with nice flowing loops works best. There is a sweet spot in terms of mesh density, ballpark for a shirt the arm loops should have 8-12 vertices. Any more and the sim may tend to crumble.
4. Sometimes you want subsurf above the sim and sometimes below it, for low poly shirts you want it above.  And make sure the viewport/render levels are the same.

For convincing shirt stretches, you usually apply the simple sim, and use multi-res sculpting for the folds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
1) I have enabled self collision
2) What are the distances, right now the outer layer thickness for the human body is set to 0.02 and the inner is 0.2 (kept at the default values itself). Other than that, for the cloth collision settings i have kept the distance at 0.015 and self collision at 0.75

Comment: Finally found the way around this problem. It all boils down to the collision distances actually. The blender units were corresponding to centimeters and I was using imperial system. So i changed the cloth collision distance to 0.5 and repel distance to 0.2 and no more tears or going into another object! 

Now I understand it is very very important to actually know the amount of change that happens when we change a value in blender units, be it distance or whatever! Great learning experience!